# Embedding a PDF file in web-page: content-type octet-steam

Tags: javascript, angular, html, typescript, pdf

I am working on a Angular web application and it needs to display PDF files from remote servers inside a web page.

I used **iframe** for this purpose. Here "path" being the URL for the pdf in remote server.

```
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" [src]="path | safe"></iframe>
```

With test pdf files it works perfectly fine until I  moved into production environment. The PDFs are get downloaded instead of displayed when the page opens. A little digging shows that the problem is that the response header contains content-type: **application/octet-stream** instead of **application/pdf**.

I've been trying to search for a solution. I find suggestions that change the content-type header will work. But in this case, it is a remote server that I do not have control on.

I also tried other tags like **embed**. It can specify file type.

```
<embed [src]="path | safe" type="application/pdf" width="300" height="200">
```

Still it does not work and displays a blank box.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Update**: I discovered that PDF file server also do not support CORS requests. How Exciting!

I've revisited ng2-pdf-viewer and it seems not that bad, but it requires CORS. Same reason pdf.js does not work. Guess that left me with a proxy server solution. Thanks guys for your help.

Comment: Why not try a component library like https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-pdf-viewer

Comment: I tried once, the display is off place, cause the page slow down considerably, and gave errors that I do not know how to fix.  I will try again if I do not have other options.

Comment: You could create a backend that proxies the request and adds the `application/pdf` content type

Comment: Thank you, I will consider that. Can it be done in Angular only? Seems too much hassle to maintain a server for that purpose.

Comment: Does this work? https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js

Comment: Thank you I will take a look.